# Safari and requestAnimationFrame gets DOMHighResTimestamp; window.performance not available

Tags: javascript, safari, timestamp, requestanimationframe

I created an animation using `requestAnimationFrame`. Works fine in Windows Chrome and IE; Safari (tested Safari 6 and 7) breaks. It turns out that rAF get a `DOMHighResTimestamp` rather than a `Date` timestamp. That's all fine and good, and what I expected, as it's now part of the spec. However, as far as I've been able to find, there's no way to get the current `DOMHighResTimestamp` (i.e. `window.performance` is not available, even with a prefix). So if I create the start time as a `Date` timestamp, it behaves radically wrong when I try to determine progress within the rAF callback (very small negative numbers).

If you look at [this](http://jsbin.com/rezej/3/edit) JSBin on Safari, it won't animate at all.

In [this](http://jsbin.com/nebul/5/edit) JBin, I've made a change to "skip" the first frame (where the `time` parameter is `undefined`), so that `startTime` gets set to the `time` parameter on the next frame. Seems to work, but skipping a frame seems a bit crappy.

Is there some way to get the current `DOMHighResTimestamp` in Safari, given the lack of `window.performance`? Or alternately, force rAF into some sort of legacy mode that forces it to get a Date timestamp instead?

Does anyone know why Safari has this inconsistency, where it provides the parameter in a format that you can't get at any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance.now() is only a recommendation as of now. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29) I can only assume it's a matter of time before it's official, seeing as how everyone but Safari has it built in.

Besides that fact use this to your advantage. Since you know requestAnimationFrame returns a DOMHighResTimestamp use that for your timing.

```
Game.start = function(timestamp){
    if(timestamp){
        this.time = timestamp;
        requestAnimationFrame(Game.loop);
    }else{
        requestAnimationFrame(Game.start);
    }
}

Game.loop = function(timestamp){
    Game.tick(timestamp);
    ... your code
    requestAnimationFrame(Game.loop);
}

Game.tick = function(timestamp) {
    this.delta      = timestamp - this.time;
    this.time       = timestamp;
};
```

What I do here, is call Game.start which will begin the loop (I've run into situations where the timestamp was undefined so we try until we get something valid). Once we get that we have our base time and since RAF is going to return a timestamp our tick function never has to call Date.now or performance.now as long as we pass it the timestamp returned by requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: That looks like basically the same approach as my second JSBin--drop the first frame and start the animation on the second frame. It works, but doesn't really answer my question as to why Safari doesn't provide any way to access a DOMHighResTimestamp outside of rAF.

Comment: That's just something they haven't implemented. I'm sure at some point they will, but for now save yourself the computations and use the one passed to you.

Comment: So I'm not missing anything--they really don't give access to DOMHighResTimestamp outside of the rAF callback?

Comment: So I did a little more digging just to verify. Found this https://www.webkit.org/blog/2188/last-week-in-webkit-conditional-css-polygonal-exclusions-and-a-few-less-prefixes/, if you read the last paragraph you would think "The vendor prefix of window.performance.now() has been removed." would mean you could use it in Safari. However all other documentation states that the performance object does not exist in Safari and I can verify that it does not exist in the latest Safari.

Comment: Interesting. Good find--so it looks like Safari is lying to us!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=performance says that in Safari 8 and 9 have support for window.performance.now(), but I just today updated from Safari 7 to Safari 9 (in Mavericks, MacBook Pro 2010) and big disappointment: window.performance is undefined!

Comment: @Timo very interesting. I just tried it in Safari 9 on El Capitan and window.performance.now() works. You wouldn't think it would be relative to the OS, but it looks like that might be the case.